# What's a pigtail with regards to antennas?

Tags: antenna

Can somebody explain to me what a pigtail is with regards to antennas? I bought a 434 MHz rod antenna with an SMA plug and what I got was the antenna as expected and another short piece of wire with another SMA plug (female plug type):

[image: pigtail?]

Is the picture above a pigtail? What's it's usage? I was able to screw on my antenna to my 434 MHz receiver without issues and have no apparent use for this other cable...

Comment: Not "433mhz" but "433 MHz" and more precisely "434 MHz"

Comment: You do solder this on the PCB where transmitter or receiver is located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pictured is a SMA connector with a pigtail,

A pigtail is a wire that ends with no connector.

you could solder that wire to something else to connect the antenna to that.

Comment: Thanks - that confirms my suspicion that it's useless in my case since the device the antenna connects to is already pre-assembled!